# nifi webgui no canvas shown after login

Tags: canvas, apache-nifi

I started nifi 1.21.0 in a k8s container. I only see the background image without an empty canvas for me to develop my flow.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you open your browser's DevTools, are there any errors in the Console or failed requests in the Network tab?

Comment: Thanks @MattGilman, I restarted chrome so I did not get a chance to check errors on front end but it indeed is related to front-end browser.

Comment: If you had previously used this browser to access a different NiFi version, it's possible that maybe there were some older resources cached. Restarting may have cleared the browser cache. A hard refresh may have been able to help too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be browser related.
I changed to MS edge it works.
I also tried to restart Chrome, it then also works for me.